# Is there a way to clear the canvas if using tkinter and writing on it again with a different message?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I have created a game it uses tkinter to open a GUI. It has a timer and when the timer runs out I want it to clear the GUI and have a message for example: Time up, you scored + there score. 
I have been able to make a label that does this on the GUI but just stays there even if the timer doesnt = 0. 
Here is the source code:

```
import tkinter
import random

colours = ['Red','Blue','Green','Pink','Black','Yellow','Orange','White','Purple','Brown']

score=0
timeleft=30
def startGame(event):
    if timeleft == 30:
        countdown()

    nextColour()

def nextColour():
    global score
    global timeleft

    if timeleft > 0:
    e.focus_set()

    if e.get().lower() == colours[1].lower():
        score += 1
    e.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    random.shuffle(colours)
    label.config(fg=str(colours[1]), text=str(colours[0]))
    scoreLabel.config(text="Score: " + str(score))

def countdown():
    global timeleft

    if timeleft > 0:
        timeleft -= 1
        timeLabel.config(text="Time left: " + str(timeleft))
        timeLabel.after(1000, countdown)
    if timeleft == 0:
        canvas.delete("all")
        endGame.config(text="Time up, you scored " + str(score))


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("TTCANTW")
root.geometry("375x250")

instructions = tkinter.Label(root, text="Type in the colour of the words,     and not the word text!", font=('ariel', 12))
instructions.pack()

endGame = tkinter.Label(root, text="Time up, you scored " + str(score), font=('ariel', 12))
endGame.pack()

scoreLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="Press enter to start", font=   ('Helvetica', 12))
scoreLabel.pack()

timeLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="Time left: " + str(timeleft), font=('Helvetica', 12))
timeLabel.pack()


label = tkinter.Label(root, font=('Helvetica', 60))
label.pack()


e = tkinter.Entry(root)

root.bind('<Return>', startGame)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't have canvas widget, impossible to delete
you have to use destroy to delete every widgets you want to delete..
I edited your function

```
def countdown():
    global timeleft

    if timeleft > 0:
        timeleft -= 1
        timeLabel.config(text="Time left: " + str(timeleft))
        timeLabel.after(1000, countdown)

    if timeleft == 0:
        #canvas.delete("all")
        instructions.destroy()
        timeLabel.destroy()
        label.destroy()
        e.destroy()
        #-------------------------
        endGame.config(text="Time up, you scored " + str(score))
```